# How to pass value from html to django view?

Tags: django

I have an option list in html.

```
<select>
        <option value="Please select" disabled selected>- Please Select -</option>
        <option value="Iphone">Iphone</option>
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
</select>
```

When the user select one of the option, the particular table with data will appear.

In views.py:

```
dev_model = Device.objects.filter(name='name').all()
```

I want to get the data from html, then filter the option with my database in field `'name'`.

If they are same, the data will be retrieved and display in html.

Comment: `<select class="chosen" style="width:350px" multiple="true">`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a [Django Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) to accomplish this.

In a file called `forms.py` (in the same directory as your `models.py`) you will have something like:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    NAME_CHOICES = (('Iphone', 'Iphone'),
                    'Samsung', 'Samsung'))
    name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=NAME_CHOICES)
```

Then, in your view, pass the form through context and render it in your django template. I would suggest `ModelForm` instead of `Form` a lot of the time, but I don't have any specifics about your application/use case.

When the form is `POST`ed back to your view, you should be able to get the data by using

```
form=MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    name = form['name'].value()
```

The link to the documentation should be a good point to get you started

To display the data as soon as the user selects the correct field, you can do this with one of two approaches:

- Use [`ajax`](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) if you want the filtering to happen on the server side
- Use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to pass all the data to the browser and have the user filter their display at their convenience.

You question is too broad to provide a specific answer while lacking the necessary details behind your attempt I have provided a starting point for your forms and links to the necessary documentation. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
You can keep mapping of device to a particular value like this:-
```

DEVICE_TO_MAPPING = {
    0:'Samsung',
    1:'Iphone',
}

And then use this mapping to send in context as variable like "devicemapping" to render in html in template, you can do it like.

```
<form name="device-form" method='POST' action='.'>
    <select>
    <option value="{{device_value}}" disabled selected>- Please Select -</option>
    {% for device_value, device_name in devicemapping.items %}
        <option name='{{device_value' value="{{device_value}}">{{ device_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

In your views.py you can filter the data using Mapping.

```
device_value = request.POST.get('device_value')
device_name = DEVICE_TO_MAPPING.get(device_value)
dev_model = Device.objects.filter(name=device_name)
```

Comment: i get this error: `Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'devicemapping.items()'`. I tried to remove the (), but still can't get the data.

Comment: And also my database is huge, if using direct mapping, it would be very complicated.

Comment: can you please share your html and python code, and if you do not want to keep mapping you can fetch the id and name from database and send in your context as dictionary